# upgrading to an unofficial rom

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have lg prada 3.0 running android 2.3.7.
Inspite of all my attempts to update to the official ICS (4.0) rom I faced alote of errors , And finally I decided not to update!
now I want to know if I can install Cyanogenmod 10.2 rom on android 2.3.7 without upgrading to the last official rom? I mean ,will I face any errors doing this?

Answer (score 0):

According to

> #### Initial install
>
> Make sure you are updated to stock LG ICS update (v20d) prior flashing the first time.
>
> And remember to wipe data/cache
>
> (These steps need only to be done once. Later updates can be just flashed over an existing installation without the need of a wipe)
>
> From:[[ROM][P940][JB][4.3.1] CyanogenMod 10.2 for LG Prada 3.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2538339)

please check which LG ICS update you've already had> If your update name is different than that, please don't do it or you would brick your device.

Check if there are any similar ICS update issue, if not create a new topic.

Hope it help